# weird error happening - discord.py rewrite json manipulation

Tags: python, discord.py

So i'm trying to register a user into my Karma system.. I use the code 2 times for 2 similar systems. One is currency and one is levels (this one is levels).

I get the error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def karmaregister(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in karma:
        karma[id] = 0
        await ctx.send("You are now registered to karma in AccoladeBot.")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already are registered to karma.")
```

Comment: Based on the error and the code I think this is the issue: `if id not in karma` => `karma` is a command, not a collection

Comment: `karma` isn't defined in the code you shared.

Comment: karma is a json file

Comment: What happens when you `print(type(karma)`

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I fixed it by realising i don't need the currency